# Анимация JQuery. Как вернуть квадрат обратно?

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Как при втором нажатии на кнопку вернуть квадрат обратно? Код ниже.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
    });
    
    
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>

<button>Start Animation</button>

<p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>

<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("div").animate({left: 0});`

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы он останавливался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте toggleclass и transition для плавности:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
        $("div").toggleClass('move_right');
    });
```

```css
div {
  left: 0px;
  transition: all .5s;
  background:#98bf21;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
}
.move_right {
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Start Animation</button>

<p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>

<div></div>
```

Comment: Чёт я записываю по ходу коряво всё))

Comment: что коряво? добавил ваш html ещё - нажмите выполнить код, вроде то, что вы хотите...

Comment: Да, теперь гуд) Просто я думал что это можно сделать с помощью animate )

Comment: есть много способов решения задачи - я предложил один из них....

Answer (score 0):

```
    [https://codepen.io/mario-web/pen/JJzaKB][1]

    <div class="box"></div>
    <button>click my</button>

    .box{
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background: #000000;
      margin: 0px;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

    $(function(){
      $('button').on('click', function(){
        var $box = $('.box');
          $box.animate({
            left: "150px"
          }, 1000)
          .animate({
            left: 0
          }, 1000)
      });
    });
```

Comment: Вот пожалуйста, по клику плавное перемещение блока, и возврат на место при помощи animate